# reading json with dojo to show in grid

Tags: json, dojo

I have been struggeling all day to read a json file from server and view it via dojo datagrid. Please see the code snippets below and help me if possible :

the html file is ::

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../_static/js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
    />
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "../../_static/js/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css"; @import "../../_static/js/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css";
        .dojoxGrid table { margin: 0; } html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%;
        margin: 0; }
    </style>
</head>

<body class=" claro ">
    <div id="gridContainer4" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");        
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
    dojo.require("dojox.data.CsvStore");

    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        // our test data store for this example:
        var store4 = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
    url: "http://localhost/test1.json"});

        // set the layout structure:
        var layout4 = [{
            field: 'abbr',
            name: 'Title of Movie',
            width: '200px'
        },
        {
            field: 'name',
            name: 'Year',
            width: '50px'
        },
        {
            field: 'capital',
            name: 'Producer',
            width: 'auto'
        }];

        // create a new grid:
        var grid4 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            query: {
                abbr: '*'
            },
            store: store4,
            clientSort: true,
            rowSelector: '20px',
            structure: layout4
        },
        document.createElement('div'));

        // append the new grid to the div "gridContainer4":
        dojo.byId("gridContainer4").appendChild(grid4.domNode);

        // Call startup, in order to render the grid:
        grid4.startup();
    });
</script>
<!-- NOTE: the following script tag is not intended for usage in real
world!! it is part of the CodeGlass and you should just remove it when
you use the code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        if (document.pub) {
            document.pub();
        }
    });
</script>
```

The json is ::

```
{ identifier: 'abbr',
          label: 'name',
          items: [
                { abbr:'ec', name:'Ecuador',           capital:'Quito' },
                { abbr:'eg', name:'Egypt',             capital:'Cairo' },
                { abbr:'sv', name:'El Salvador',       capital:'San Salvador' },
                { abbr:'gq', name:'Equatorial Guinea', capital:'Malabo' },
                { abbr:'er', name:'Eritrea',           capital:'Asmara' },
                { abbr:'ee', name:'Estonia',           capital:'Tallinn' },
                { abbr:'et', name:'Ethiopia',          capital:'Addis Ababa' }
        ]}
```

Comment: So what exactly isn't working here?  It seems to work fine for me if I throw it into a jsfiddle (only difference is I threw the data into the store directly rather than via separate URL): http://jsfiddle.net/LRnhu/1/ - if you're having a problem specifically pulling in the JSON externally, make sure the URL is correct and that it's referencing the same domain (since it uses XHR which isn't permitted across domains).  Also as Oleg mentioned, having it in valid JSON format is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not use dojo, but if the file content of test1.json is really as you wrote at the end of your post, then it is wrong. In [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format all property names and all strings must be double quoited. So try to replace the test1.json file with the following

```
{
    "identifier": "abbr",
    "label": "name",
    "items": [
        { "abbr": "ec", "name": "Ecuador", "capital": "Quito" },
        { "abbr": "eg", "name": "Egypt", "capital": "Cairo" },
        { "abbr": "sv", "name": "El Salvador", "capital": "San Salvador" },
        { "abbr": "gq", "name": "Equatorial Guinea", "capital": "Malabo" },
        { "abbr": "er", "name": "Eritrea", "capital": "Asmara" },
        { "abbr": "ee", "name": "Estonia", "capital": "Tallinn" },
        { "abbr": "et", "name": "Ethiopia", "capital": "Addis Ababa" } 
    ]
}
```

A good place where you can validate your JSON data is http://www.jsonlint.com/.

Comment: @user344788. Does it help? Could you does forward? Probably you should use `dojo.xhrGet()` to load the data. Look at following links http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2010-January/042254.html, http://doc-staging.dojocampus.org/quickstart/ajax.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423459/datagrid-in-dojo-with-json-data-from-a-servlet