# Dojo DataGrid Not Showing

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

In my `dojo.xhrGet` I have specified this `load:`:

```
load: function (data) {
    // reset data display containers
    dojo.addClass("search_results", "hide_on_load");
    dojo.byId("search_results_found").innerHTML = "";
    // populate table with new results.
    dojo.byId("search_results_found").innerHTML = "" + data.length + " search result(s) found.";

    // when data is from an XHR request, you must transform it into a store.
    // See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423459/datagrid-in-dojo-with-json-data-from-a-servlet
    var items = dojo.map(data, function (res_row) {
        return {
            'Id': res_row.Id,
            'Name': res_row.Name,
            'VisitType': res_row.VisitType,
            'VisitDate': res_row.VisitDate
        };
    });

    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        data: {
            items: items
        }
    });

    var res_layout = [
        {field: 'Id',        name: 'ID',         width: '10%'},
        {field: 'Name',      name: 'Site Name',  width: '50%'},
        {field: 'VisitType', name: 'Visit Type', width: '20%'},
        {field: 'VisitDate', name: 'Visit Date', width: '20%'}
        ];

    // create a new grid:
    var res_grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        store: store,
        structure: res_layout,
        rowsPerPage: 10
    }, document.createElement('div'));

    // append the new grid to the div "search_results_table":
    dojo.byId("search_results_table").appendChild(res_grid.domNode);

    // Call startup, in order to render the grid:
    res_grid.startup();

    dojo.removeClass("search_results", "hide_on_load");
    standby.hide();
},
```

And, the html is:

```
<!-- Search Results Table -->
<div id="search_results" class="hide_on_load">
    <div id="search_results_found"></div>
    <div id="search_results_table"></div>
</div>
```

At the end of this script, the grid does not show.

I removed the hide_on_load css class selector so that I could exclude it as being the issue.  But, that did not help.

Looking at the console, there are no errors logged.

Also, writing the various objects (res_grid, store, etc.) all produce output that looks to be correct.

Can somebody provide some help on how to get it to show?

Thanks!

**Update:**

When I inspect the DOM after this code has run, I see the tabler created with the headers but then when I go to find the actual table with the search results (under `div class=dojoxGridContent`), it isn't there.

**Update 2:**

I have the styles specified too:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css";
    @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css";
    .dojoxGrid table { margin: 0; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set a size through the style property on the div where you place your grid, and don't forget to import the CSS files for your grid, like :

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import "dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css";
    @import "dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/soriaGrid.css";

    .dojoxGrid table {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Note : Replace soria by whatever theme you are using...

... and don't forget to set a size to your grid's dom node :

```
<div id="gridnode" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you try to put a width and height on your div, like "<div id="search_results_table" style='width:100%;height:300px'></div>" ?

Comment: Yep, that did it!!!! Thank you Philipe! Would you update your answer and then I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a fix height you can declare the grid with`autoHeight: true`.

```
var res_grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({

        store: store,
        structure: res_layout,
        rowsPerPage: 10,
        autoHeight: true
    }, document.createElement('div'));
```

With This attribute you don't need to add style to the parent container for it to display.